# Storing time zone indicator in the database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

We have an API in ASP.NET Core 3.1 and there's a scenario where we need to store hours of operation values for businesses in the database.

As a general rule, we store all `DateTime` values in UTC along with UTC offset values to make conversions easy.

However, in this case, using UTC offset wouldn't work because daylight savings time adjustments are ever changing due to regulations, etc. As a result, we may end up with a new UTC offset value other than the one we stored in the database and end up returning inaccurate data.

Asking users to choose a time zone is probably one of the most un-user-friendly things to do. Especially in .NET/.NET Core, the list of time zones is very long and could be overwhelming for most users.

What other alternatives do we have in using a time zone indicator that would be more robust than using just the UTC offset and better than asking user to pick a time zone from a long list?

Comment: I have used this javascript to retrieve the time zone identifier (IANA format): https://github.com/pellepim/jstimezonedetect that works well with the NodaTime library (https://nodatime.org/).